# Modifying Qt Library

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qt5

I am developing a project using the QCanBusDevice library provided by Qt in 5.10 version. However, the readFrame() API to read can frames from a QVector input buffer is too slow. It can't keep up with the amount of CAN messages the processor is throwing.

I want to be able to flush the buffer and obtain the latest data on the wire, however, the library doesn't provide any API to flush the input buffer (please let me know if I missed that).

Is it possible to modify this library and add a flush API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Is it possible to modify this library and add a flush API?"

Of course it is. Qt is open-source, you can download the source code, make the modification you need, recompile the library and then use your modified version with your application.

At the place I work we do exactly this to add a few bits and pieces we need and fix some bugs.

But if you do this, please submit your changes back to the project so a) others can benefit, and b) you don't have to maintain your own fork indefinitely (at my company we, of course, also do this).

Comment: Hi Jesper, thanks for the confirmation. I would really appreciate if you could give me some pointers to get started or give me a link where I can read about compiling the Qt source.

Comment: @Prateek Khatri  Start here: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/build-sources.html also read: http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Contribution_Guidelines

Comment: not that it matters, but "we also do this" is ambiguous. Do you also maintain your fork indefinitely?

Comment: I guess I need the Commercial License to do this.. :(

Comment: @tobi303 We always try to contribute all changes back and work with the Qt developers to morph our changes into something that's acceptable upstream. Many times they take our changes/fixes, but sometimes they don't. So we have a small set of patches we maintain locally because upstream does not want them and then we have a few patches we maintain locally because we cannot (yet) upgrade to the version where they have been merged upstream. In short; we try to be good open-source citizens :)

Comment: @Prateek Khatri - "I guess I need the Commercial License to do this" - I am not a lawyer, but I don't think you do - as long as you publish your modifications.

Comment: sounds cool, unfortunately I never had the pleasure to work on some bigger opensource project